# Only entering function once in for init statement

Tags: go

I am starting programming with Go and I am trying to create a program that makes queries to a DB and return the data. I have achieved this but I have encounter some problems and questions during this.

Firstly, I tried to create a for with a condition to tell the program when I want to stop making queries, but the Init Statement of the for looks that only is evaluated once -and I am never asked again to enter input via terminal- (I have read here that is because his value is hold and then it doesnt execute the function again: [Golang switch statement only calls function once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262903/golang-switch-statement-only-calls-function-once) ):

**Edited**

```
func main() {
    var query string
    for query = ReadQuery(); query != "exit\n"; {
        rows, err := db.Query(query)
        //Printing results and other operations
    }
    fmt.Println("Exiting")
}

func ReadQuery() string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter query in a single line, with no newline. 'exit' to terminate execution: \n")
    query, _ :=reader.ReadString('\n')
    reader.Reset(os.Stdin)
    return query
}
```

...so I have done this fix that looks to me a bit dirty:

```
func main() {
    var query string
    for {
        query = ReadQuery()
        if query == "exit\n" {
            fmt.Println("Exiting")
            break
        }
        //Printing results and other operations
    }
}

func ReadQuery() string {
   reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
   fmt.Print("Enter query in a single line, with no newline. 'exit' to terminate execution: \n")
   query, _ :=reader.ReadString('\n')
   reader.Reset(os.Stdin)
   return query
}
```

So the question is if there is another way to do this using for statements and  avoid more lines to my code. Lot of thanks

Comment: Have you considered `for q := f(); q != "exit"; q = f() {`? [example](https://play.golang.com/p/N8uerScb1kg)

Comment: You have waaay too much code in your question. If "Only the first three lines are important", please include only the first three lines. In general, post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You seem to be aware that the init statement of a for loop is executed just once and this is your problem. So what is the actual question?

Comment: Thanks, mkopriva, didnt considered that!
Yes, you are right, Flimzy, I will clean a bit the post to make it more legible to anyone who has the same problem.
I was looking for a more clear implementation of what I wanted to do, Volker.
Thanks you all for the fast responses

Comment: That's pretty much the definition of "init statement". It *initializes* the loop. If it ran more than once, that would be extremely misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a post statement to your loop that will be called on each iteration.

```
var query string
for query = ReadQuery(); query != "exit\n"; query = ReadQuery() {
    // loop body
}
```

The [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1) has a good explanation of this functionality.